# AzureCP does not return results from Central Administration

Tags: claims, azure-ad

My environment is SharePoint 2013 authenticating through Azure AD via ADFS.  I am using AzureCP v12.Beta as the claims provider.

AzureCP does not return results from Central Administration but all other web applications work fine.

From the 'Add users to this group' dialog, I see "Sorry, we're having trouble reaching the server."  From the Web Applications page -> User Policy -> Add Users -> 'Select People and Groups' dialog, I get the error "No results were found to match your search item.  Please enter a new term or less specific term.  This is true even when selecting 'Bypass Azure AD lookup' from the AzureCP configuration page.

I see the following in ULS:

> [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 05/10/2018 11:05:04.64, Original Level: Verbose] TenantAppEtag record requested but there is no sitesubscription or tenantId for site {0} so we will use the WebApp Id for the cache.
>
> [AzureCP] Unexpected error in FillSearch: System.ArgumentException: Exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' was thrown.  Parameter name: encodedValue, Callstack:
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimEncodingManager.DecodeClaimFromFormsSuffix(String encodedValue)
>    at azurecp.RequestInformation..ctor(IAzureCPConfiguration currentConfiguration, RequestType currentRequestType, List`1 processedClaimTypeConfigList, String input, SPClaim incomingEntity, Uri context, AzureADObjectType[] directoryObjectTypes, String hierarchyNodeID, Int32 maxCount)
>    at azurecp.AzureCP.FillSearch(Uri context, String[] entityTypes, String searchPattern, String hierarchyNodeID, Int32 maxCount, SPProviderHierarchyTree searchTree)
>
> Claims Search call failed. Error Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  Callstack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleQueryControl.IssueClaimsQuery(String searchPattern, String providerID, String hierarchyNodeID, Int32 pageSize, SPProviderHierarchyTree spgroupTree).

The Active Directory `spclaimprovider` was disabled via the following:

`$cpm = Get-SPClaimProviderManager
$ad = get-spclaimprovider -identity "AD"
$ad.IsVisible = $false
$cpm.Update()`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug that has been resolved with the latest release of the AzureCP v.12 beta.